# Prove that the set used in archimedean property is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x$ be a positive real number. Show that the set 
$\{nx:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R$.

What I tried to do is that consider the function $f (x)=nx$ which is continuous in $\Bbb R$ and tried to show that $g (x)=f (x)-nx$  greater than $0$ or less than $0$ is an open set.

Is my approach right ?

Please help!

Comment: I dk what you are thinking. If $f(x)=x$ then $0=nx-nx=f(x)-nx=g(x).$

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1) Show the compliment is open. 
That’s is, the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{xN}$ is open. This is easy since every number in this set can reside in a ball of radius smaller than the nearest $nx$. This might need to be done using two separate cases: $x = 0$ and $x \not = 0$.

Clearly the first case is easy. The second is slightly harder.

2) Show the set contains all its limit points.
This might be a bit harder.

Comment: So do we need to apply archime dean property

Comment: For the case x is not zero, then we take a number in the set R \ N, say y. Now dividing that number by x, we get, y/x. By the Archimedean property, there exist n such that n <= y/x <= n+1. So xn <= y <= x(n+1). Now you just need to show that this y is in an open ball

Comment: Complement, not compliment. Related to the word "complete".

Answer (score 0):

(gdepaul's answer contains suggestions for alternate approaches. This one focuses on the idea laid out in the question)

And where would you go from there? You went from a fixed $x$ and an infinite collection of $n$ to a fixed $n$ and variable $x$; to recover the set we care about, we would have to take an intersection of infinitely many versions. That - well, an intersection of infinitely many open sets is not necessarily open.

I don't see this approach working.